# Why the package level pointer variable is not assigned?

Tags: go

In the following code, `router` is package level variable that points to a struct. This pointer is initialized in `main` function. But the pointer is still nil in  initializeRoutes function.

go version go1.14.6 windows/amd64

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)


var router *gin.Engine

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    initializeRoutes()
    router.Run()
}

func initializeRoutes() {
    fmt.Println(router)
    // here the router is nil
}
```

Comment: "But it can't be accessed in another function within the same package." -- Yes it can. Why do you think it can't?

Comment: edit the description, nil doesn't mean 'inaccessible'.

Comment: that is my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing the global variable `router` with the `:=` operator in `main`:

```
var router *gin.Engine

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()  // make a new variable called "router", shadowing the global var
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    initializeRoutes()
    router.Run()
}

func initializeRoutes() {
    fmt.Println(router)  // this doesn't know about main's "router", so sees the global var
}
```

To fix this, do not use the `:=` operator. Use plain old assignment instead:

```
var router *gin.Engine

func main() {
    router = gin.Default()  // assigns to the global var
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    initializeRoutes()
    router.Run()
}

func initializeRoutes() {
    fmt.Println(router)
}
```

See [this playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/3D2hytThCGq) for a simpler example of this in action.